# Splitting an array into n parts and then joining them again forming a histogram

Tags: arrays, matlab, histogram

I am new to Matlab.

Lets say I have an array `a = [1:1:1000]`

I have to divide this into 50 parts `1-20`; `21-40` .... `981-1000`.

I am trying to do it this way.

```
E=1000X
a=[1:E]
n=50
d=E/n
b=[]
for i=0:n
   b(i)=a[i:d]
end
```

But I am unable to get the result.

And the second part I am working on is, depending on another result, say if my answer is 3, the first split array should have a counter and that should be +1, if the answer is 45 the 3rd split array's counter should be +1 and so on and in the end I have to make a histogram of all the counters.

Comment: -1 for not even bothering to google or search SO first.  First two results for google search "matlab histogram" are hist() (the plot) and histc() (the binning function).  on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=matlab+histogram  Your answer is the second link.  This isn't supposed to be a substitute for doing some work yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do all of this with [one function](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/histc.html): `histc`. In your situation:

```
X = (1:1:1000)';
Edges = (1:20:1000)';
Count = histc(X, Edges);
```

Essentially, `Count` contains the number of elements in `X` that fall into the categories defined in `Edges`, where `Edges` is a monotonically increasing vector whose elements define the boundaries of sequential categories. A more common example might be to construct `X` using a probability density, say, the uniform distribution, eg:

```
X = 1000 * rand(1000, 1);
```

Play around with specifications for `X` and `Edges` and you should get the idea. If you want the actual histogram plot, look into the `hist` function.

As for the second part of your question, I'm not really sure what you're asking.